# add url in jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm having trouble with jquery accordion menu. I want ONLY the text "Chewable Oraldolphilus" go to a url. The requirement is that it should work with click not mouseover. Right now when you click anywhere next to a link it goes to a url instead of just expanding the accordion. Please advise. Thanks.

http://www.maxihealth.com/test/accordion3.html

Comment: Please post the code inside SO to visually see it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at the source code, but the following should work:

```
$(".head > div:first-child").click("function(){
 $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
  return false // this prevents the default behavior (changing the location of the page)  
}")
```